# Pivotal quantity of exponential model

Tags: distributions, estimation, pivot

I'm attempting to solve this problem but it's been driving me crazy. The goal it's to find a pivotal quantity of the model below and a symmetric confidence interval for $\theta$ with an $(1-\alpha)$ level from a sample of size $n$ from the model.

$$F_\theta(x) = 1 - (1-x)^{-\theta}; x > 0; \theta > 0$$

I've tried to make a similarity with an exponential distribution but I don't really think that it's a correct assumption. I've also searched just in case I found some similar distribution solved with this method but I found nothing similar. How could it be solved with the pivotal quantity approach?

Comment: Please check, sure that is a cumulative distribution function?